# Good examples for methods section in math or computer science

Tags: publications, methodology

A methods section is very common in areas such as medicine. However, in math
or computer science papers I rarely find such a section if no experiments or
observational studies were conducted. Nevertheless, it is a requirement for
the computer science journal I submitted to. While nearly none of the papers
published by the journal provides one, I still have to fulfill this requirement.

While some general guidelines can be found, for example in [this question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/68040/what-is-the-difference-between-the-method-and-experimental-setup-section),
it would be very helpful to have some good examples for such a section in existing math or computer science literature.

**Edit:** As clarification: I already submitted and got a revision request that did not mention a missing methods second. I then submitted a revision and after a few hours I got a second revision request asking for a methods section (and a few other formal requests). I know that I could discuss this with the editor if I really need one, but maybe it would actually improve the paper.

Comment: You're written "it is a requirement for the computer science journal I *submitted to*," surely you mean *want to submit to*, otherwise, it is to late to fulfil the requirement. (Sorry for being pedantic, I just want to understand your situation.)

Answer (score 1):

Since "none of the papers published by the journal provides [a methods section]," despite the journal's requirement for such a section, you needn't fulfil this requirement.* (It is perhaps a generic requirement that most of the publisher's journals demand, but isn't required by the journal you're submitting to.)

*You can confirm with the editor, to be absolutely sure.